# Why is $\int_{-\infty}^\infty |\text{sinc}(t)|\ dt=\infty$?

Tags: integration, harmonic-analysis, harmonic-functions

Can you help me with that:

> Why is $\int_{-\infty}^\infty |\text{sinc}(t)|\ dt=\infty$ ?

I saw this in Signal Processing course and I can’t understand why this is true.

Reference: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/1033/49921

Didn’t find any relevant material unfortunately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$ \int_0^{+\infty}\frac{|\sin(t)|}{t}dt=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\int_{n\pi}^{(n+1)\pi}\frac{|\sin(t)|}{t}dt=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\int_0^{\pi}\frac{|\sin u|}{u+n\pi}du \\ \geqslant \int_0^{\pi}|\sin u|du\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{(n+1)\pi}=\frac{2}{\pi}\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{n}=+\infty $$

Comment: It’s $\infty*0$ is it $\infty$?

Comment: It depends, but $\int_0^{\pi}|\sin(u)|du=2$ here

Comment: Wait why is the sum then is $\infty$?

Comment: Because of Chasles relation

Comment: I don’t see info on Chasels relation I can understand and relate to it. Is it 100% true? Sorry I nudge you.

Comment: Yes, I just used $$ \int_a^b f+\int_b^c f=\int_a^c f $$This is Chasles relation. SInce the integration goes to $+\infty$, the sum goes to $+\infty$ aswell

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106885/discussion-between-vitali-pom-and-tuvasbien).

Comment: The sum is just the harmonic series which is known to be divergent.

Comment: But https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_tests here it says it shall converge @Gary What do I miss?

Comment: I apologies I drive you crazy :)

Comment: @VitaliPom : Nothing on the convergence tests page claims that the [harmonic series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)) converges.  And for good reason, it does not.  Use the integral test from the page you cite to show that it does not.

Comment: I see Leibnitz Criterion says it converges. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Sorry I’m confused (((((

Comment: It says that $\sum\frac{(-1)^n}{n}$ converges, not $\sum\frac{1}{n}$

Comment: Ok. Reset. I’m checking now. Thanks! Tuvasbien and all the others.

Comment: The harmonic series is the classical example of a series whose terms tend to $0$ yet the series diverges.

Comment: https://www.quora.com/Why-does-1-n-diverge Mark Regan explained that on Quora. Many thanks gang for the patience! You’re the best.